# Load balance (or http proxy) by the logged in user of a Django app?

Tags: django, load-balancing

What is an efficient way to load balance (or in a sense shard) users of a Django app by their username?  I want to flag certain users of the Django app and have them go to a different web server once they are logged in.

Comment: Are you trying to implement persistence in load balancing? Is that it?

Comment: @andrefsp Yes.  In a more fundamental way, I'm trying to have certain users assigned to certain production nodes.  e.g.:European users who log in always route to our European production node by their username.  I'd want to have those European servers be located in the area, and get "turned around" (loaded with new software/DB migrations) during European off-hours.

Comment: I would do something like setting a cookie on user's browser, and than using a back proxy(such as nginx) to read the cookie and redirect the user to the proper web server. 
May I ask why are you trying to do such thing? Trying to implement sticky sessions can be a big nightmare

Comment: I've had a similar issue. Ended up using a modified version of [balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) (a TCP balancer) where instead of using hashing, I hooked it with an IP-Region table.

Comment: @MikeN I think you looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS . Before even user touch your front-end servers he get address your nearest cluster. This question more suitable for serverfault.com

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Anycast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast)!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have specific users on a specific server: Create multiple subdomains (www.example.com, www1.example.com, www2.example.com etc). Once a user is logged in, check if the user is on the correct domain/server. If not, do a redirect to the users subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

we are using HA-Proxy to handle similar requirements for 18 different applications hosted on 34+ servers.

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/
https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/

if you need further help on how to configure it, i'll be ready to help.

hope that's help.

Answer (score 0):

after login you could setup additional cookie with username (hash of it, hash of email, hash of user_id, etc.)

and by using ha-proxy you could load-balance based on cookie. More information is available in documentation for ha-proxy (but I believe nginx could do it also).